# Screen went blank, and now only boots into Lowlatency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

A couple weeks ago my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS suddenly stopped recognizing my Dell external monitor (it still works on Windows - I'm using dual boot) so I tried using different Nvida drivers in Ubuntu to see if I could get it working, but then the screen went blank and I haven't been able to get it working again. When I try booting into Recovery Mode it gets hung up on boot with the message "Loading initial ramdisk...". Then I have to reboot it and start it in lowlatency mode. That works fine. Changing the Nvidia driver in lowlatency mode doesn't do anything. I tried updating all my software, and just upgraded to 23.04, but that didn't resolve the issue either. Any ideas?

Comment: Guys, is there any more information I can add to make this issue easier to solve? One thing that came to mind is the moment the screen went blank I was also working on trying to recover some corrupt video files. I think I was loading them in Kdenvideo editor to try to save them. I don't know if that's related or not.